# How to automatically clear items in Trash after a week?

Tags: macos, trash

I'm using macOS High Sierra. It has a feature to automatically clear items in Trash after they are deleted for 30 days. But I want to clear items in a week. Is it possible?

Comment: In the linked Dupe, there are multiple ways to do this - using a script and via Automator.  Just change the `~/Downloads` directory to `~/.Trash`

Comment: To Close Voters: IMO I don't see this as a duplicate of the linked question because Trash is not a singular location. You can have a folder in the root mounted volumes (.Trashes), as well as in one's home folder (~/.Trash). The root Trash folder (.Trashes) in any attached volume has several folders within, one for each User that deleted files that are not in their own folder. The most voted answer in the linked question is severely flawed, see second comment to it. Emptying the root Trash folder from other then the GUI requires `sudo` for any command line methods.